# How to add third-party dependency javascript to Shopware 6

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I would like to add third-party dependency to Shopware6 e.g. `https://github.com/vimeo/player.js/` for vimeo support. I'm not sure how to do it in the right way. Should I add dependencies to package.json somewhere or maybe create a vendor folder in my plugin where I will store this code file, that I can import at the point of use? Maybe there is some other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add a dependency to your administration module, just create your `package.json` within `src/Resources/app/administration` and install your dependency. Those dependencies will be automatically detected by the webpack compiler, so you just have to import your library as normal within your module/component e.g

```
import package from 'package';
```

You don't need to ship the plugin later with the whole `node_modules` folder because Shopware is using only the compiled javascript ( `administration:build` ) for the plugin installation.

You can take a look at our [Shopware-Maps Repo](https://github.com/Shape-and-Shift/shopware-maps) how we did it with the Mapbox dependency for example.