# How to add package.json to storefront plugin in Shopware 6?

Tags: shopware

Based on this answer [How to add third-party dependency javascript to Shopware 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63841395/how-to-add-third-party-dependency-javascript-to-shopware-6) and indicated repo I'm trying to add package.json to storefront plugin. If I run npm install in plugin everything works fine, but when there is no node_modules folder, build script doesn't generate one and build script throws an error (can't resolve modules form missing node_modules). Should I add command to dev-ops scripts (npm install for my plugin) or am I missing some configuration?

Answer (score 0):

The node_modules folder will be automatically created when running 'npm install'. Once the installation is done, the node package must be registered in the build system so that it will be considered when running 'storefront:build'. This can be done using the file 'build/webpack.config.js'. Once the build is complete, the node_modules folder can be removed just as the linked answer suggests.

The complete set of instructions can be found in this article provided by Shopware: https://www.shopware.com/en/news/installing-your-own-dependencies-via-npm/